# What is the difference between full text search and keyword search?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, information-retrieval

What is the difference between full text search and keyword search ?

Definitions are quite ok . Can anybody give brief idea what is the difference and which one is better ?

Comment: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/034498a6-d9fb-4f51-95d3-fa0ea7ac2960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information retrieval as you mention here, the ideal search for you would be keyword. And actually also pretty generally, why ?

Well, you can see to imagine every person having their own way of interpreting a subject, and giving a full text search will give you more accurate info, or no hits at all just cause of the fact that you write it in your "Own" language. Selecting your keywords correctly and keeping it short and troughout, will not only give you better results, but also clever you to keep notes for future reference and learn more in depth due to an actual word stucking to your head.